# Datepicker shows calendar on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use the following code on a text box to include a `datepicker` and set it to the current date:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
    }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
})
```

While this sets the `datepicker`'s value to the current date, it also displays the calendar in the background, like so:

[image]

The calendar is not even attached to the `datepicker` field, it just shows in the background. Why this creepy behavior and how can I fix it?

Comment: Unless you're rolling your own theme, use one of the default theme stylesheets, e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use CSS to hide it initially:

```
.ui-datepicker {
    display:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/3hA5n/)

The `datepicker` will force-display itself when necessary. For more, see [this duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580727/override-jquery-ui-datepicker-div-visible-strangely-on-first-page-load).

*Note: "As [TheSuitIsBlackNot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) pointed out, the `datepicker` doesn't display on page load if you use one of the default jQuery UI themes."*

Answer (score 1):

You may use script to resolve the datepicker display issue on page load

```
$(function() {
$('.ui-datepicker').css('display','none');
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
}).datepicker("setDate", "0");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3hA5n/1/

Comment: What do you mean "unblock"? Do you actually mean un-`display:block`?